# HTML Agility Pack - XPath Null Reference

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

Ok, so the HTMLAgilityPack XPath seems to be a hit or miss for me but I can't seem to find the issue in reference to the exception message "NullReferenceException". Below is the code I have but for this particular data, i'm getting NullReferenceExcepttion.

The XPath is a direct copy from Chrome Browser, seems to work with most html but not this particular one. Below is the code.

```
string Url = "https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=TradeHalts";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

string haltDate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"divTradeHaltResults\"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")[0].InnerText;
string haltTime = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"divTradeHaltResults\"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")[0].InnerText;
string haltSymbol = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"divTradeHaltResults\"]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")[0].InnerText;
```

Below is the HMTL block which can be followed in my XPATH. Cant seem to find the issue of why its not pulling the text value of the date, time, symbo...etc..Any help is appreciated.

```html
<div id="divTradeHaltResults"><div class="genTable"><table>
 <tbody><tr>
  <th class="gtcol1">Halt Date</th>
  <th class="gtcol2">Halt Time</th>
  <th class="gtcol3">Issue Symbol</th>
  <th class="gtcol4">Issue Name</th>
  <th class="gtcol5">Market</th>
  <th class="gtcol6">Reason Codes</th>
  <th class="gtcol7">Pause Threshold Price</th>
  <th class="gtcol8">Resumption Date</th>
  <th class="gtcol9">Resumption Quote Time</th>
  <th class="gtcol10">Resumption Trade Time</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>04/28/2017                    </td>
  <td>08:35:42                      </td>
  <td>ZLTQ</td>
  <td>ZELTIQ Aesthetics Inc</td>
  <td>NASDAQ</td>
  <td><div style="padding-bottom:2px"><a href="#" title="T12 Halt - Trading">T12</a></div></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table></div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: Also tried Selenium Firefox WebDriver and still not getting any data. below is the code snippet:

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();                      
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://weather.deltixlab.com");
IWebElement inputs = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='free-data-table']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"));

string day1 = inputs.ToString();
```

Comment: I had similar issues with HtmlAgilityPack. The XPath Chrome generated didn't match what HtmlAgilityPack wanted. My solution was to check through the NodeCollection (debugging) and manually write the XPath myself.

Comment: Why are you not using the rss feed though? http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/rss.aspx?feed=tradehalts

Comment: @naslund you know what, thats an excellent point :) didn't realize they offered an RSS feed...makes it a ton easier. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I'm going to keep this question open and see if someone can point out the issue in the XPath/HTMLAgilityPack as some sites do not offer the XML/RSS feeds and this is a reoccuring issue.

Comment: The DOM node (HTML source) is empty: `<div id="divTradeHaltResults"></div>`, which results in the null reference exception.  `HtmlWeb` does **not** pick up dynamic (XHR) content. Try a headless browser like PhantomJS or Selenium, or `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`.

Comment: @kuujinbo - Just tried Selenium Firefox WebDriver and I'm still not getting any data. Below is my code...any thoughts? 
`IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();                      
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://weather.deltixlab.com");
IWebElement inputs = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='free-data-table']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"));

string day1 = inputs.ToString();`

Comment: @kuujinbo - Ok so I updated to include Selenium and PhantomJS with the below code however my result is "Element (id = : wdc: 1496072245504". the code is below...any help is appreciated or post as an answer so i can accept.

`IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://weather.deltixlab.com");
var myNode = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='free-data-table']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]"));`